# New Task will not appear in TFS web access mode/Sprint board,when created in Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I have a scrum/Agile project running in TFS 2013. In web access mode I can define tasks and assign it to my backlog item(Work tab/Backlogs/Current/Sprint X) and it appears in [Sprint Board](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj838789.aspx) obviously. but when i want to define new task through Visual Studio/Team Explorer/Work Items,  the Iteration is my current Sprint but there`s no backlog to choose!!!
so any task that defined here will not appear in TFS board.
what kind of tasks are these??they are in my sprint but related to no backlog item!?!?
is there any way to show them in web access area??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to create a parent link to the PBI/UserStory/Requirement.

Orphan tasks won't show up in the sprint board, and one of the benefits of web access is it usually creates the links for you automatically, on VS you need to create the link manually.

Also be sure to set the area properly if you have multiple teams.

Comment: ok.i just find out in link section by adding a parent link this orphan task will get some shelter finally ;)
just check if it`s ok to add this Parent Item to the main Task requirment View.